# Why is this function segfaulting?

Tags: c++, pointers, segmentation-fault, dynamic-memory-allocation

The function is this:

```
Set::Set(Multinumber* tempArray[], int tempSize)
{
 numElements = tempSize;
 capacity = tempSize*2;
 setArray = new Multinumber*[capacity];
 for (int i=0; i<numElements; i++)
 {
  addElement(tempArray[i]);
 }
}
```

The variable setArray is declared in my header to be of type Multinumber**

It segfaults whenever I call it with this:

```
Multinumber* carr[2];
carr[0]=c4;
carr[1]=c5;
Set setb(carr,2);
```

c4 and c5 are already declared pointers to objects of the proper type.

Any help would be much appreciated.

EDIT: Code below is addElement function (apologies for the indentation)

```
const Set Set::operator+(const Set& rhs) const
{
 Set result;
 int i=0, j=0;

 while ((i < numElements) && (j < rhs.numElements))
 {
  Multinumber* toadd=new Multinumber;
  toadd=*(setArray[i]) + *(rhs.setArray[j]);
  result.addElement(toadd);
  i++;
  j++;
 }

 while ((i < numElements))
 {
  result.addElement(setArray[i]);
  i++;
 } 


 while ((j < rhs.numElements))
 {
 result.addElement(rhs.setArray[j]);
 j++;
 }


 return result;
}
```

EDIT:
Based on numerous cout statements, error seems to be in this function:

```
 bool Set::isFull()
 {
  return (numElements == capacity);
 }
```

EDIT: Changed array indices, but still segfaults

Comment: More context is needed.  A complete, compilable example would be superb.

Comment: You still haven't provided code for addElement. Likely places for errors also are the default constructor, the copy constructor and the destructor for class Set, so better post that code, too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
carr[1]=c4;
carr[2]=c5;
```

Shouldn't that be

```
carr[0]=c4;
carr[1]=c5;
```

?

Piece of advice: If you load this up in a debugger, such as gdb, it would have identified the culprit line and you would've seen your error very quickly.

Comment: Actually, still segfaults unfortunately

Comment: @Ross Can you fire the code up in gdb or another debugger and see what it tells you? Also, code for addElement() might help - I can't see anything else wrong.

Comment: added the addelement function. Unfortunately I don't have a debugger where I am right now and don't have the authority to install one on this computer. I'm pretty sure that addelement does work because I have used it at another place inthe program and it does not segfault.

Comment: Actually, adding cout statements seems to say that it *does* segfault at addElement(params)

Comment: Added another sample of code. couts say that there is no way the segfault could be anywhere else.

Comment: @Ross I strongly advise you find a way to run the code through a debugger. The segfault might manifest where you suggest, but there's no way that code you refer to has an error. With C++, the error could have occured far earlier but not result in any noticable problems until where you're seeing it segfault.

Answer (score 7):

Arrays use zero-based indexes, so setting `carr[2]` to anything in a two-length array is undefined behavior. You should be grateful it was a segfault. :-)

Try:

```
Multinumber* carr[2];
carr[0]=c4;
carr[1]=c5;
Set setb(carr,2);
```

That should take care of the segfault.

Comment: Need more context then. Please provide the definitions for the class in question...